# Know how many txt there are in a directory

Tags: c, directory, txt

i am trying to do a program that check a directory and tell me how many txt already exist so i can write a new one sequentially.
What is the best way to do that, and how i do that?

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Use `opendir()` and `readdir()` to read all the filenames and check if the name ends with `.txt`. Increment a counter as you do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dirent` header to accomplish this task.

you should iterate through every file in the folder, and then you should just do string manipulation, to get the extension of each file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>



int main() 
{
    const char *dir = ".";//current dir
    printf("opening folder\n");
    DIR *root_folder = opendir(dir);
    if(root_folder == 0) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return -1;
    }
    struct dirent *file;

    while((file = readdir(root_folder)) != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(file->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(file->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
        //you can work with the names here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar suggested, you can use the functions [opendir()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html) to open the desired directory and [readdir()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) to read its content. `readdir()` returns a pointer to a **dirent** struct. More about the struct [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html). You can later use `strrchr()` to find the last occurence of `.` and `strcmp()` to see if you have a match.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
    int txt_count = 0;
    DIR *pdir = NULL;
    struct dirent *dp = NULL;
    char *dir = "."; /* current directory, modify to match your dir */
    char *type = NULL;

    pdir = opendir(dir); /* opens directory dir */

    if (!pdir) /* check if failed to open */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open dir <%s>\n", dir);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((dp = readdir(pdir))) /* reading contents until NULL */
    {
        type = strrchr(dp->d_name, '.'); /* get a pointer to the last occurence of '.' in filename */

        if (type != NULL && !strcmp(type, ".txt")) /* compare with ".txt",check type for NULL if not found */
        {
            txt_count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Total txt files in directory </%s> --> %d\n", dir, txt_count);

    return 0;
}
```